# Чем заменить дерево вложенных классов

Tags: java

Всем добрый день.
К примеру есть какая-то сущность, которая в себе содержит как примитивы(доступ через setter/getter), так и более сложные структуры, которые в свою очередь, также могут содержать какие-то структуры.

Для реализации этого напрашивается создание класса сущности с деревом вложенных классов.
Одной из главных задач является простота использованя этого класса, т.е. вызывая последовательно его методы и вложенные классы, можно легко понять дерево/наследование.

Но у меня есть сомнения в целосообразности создания дерева вложенных классов, наверняка есть более правильные решения. 
К тому же, возможно необходимо будет использовать прокси для вложенных....

Паттернов я что-то не нашел, поэтому пршу совета как лучше организовать такую структуру.

Comment: Если у Вас сущность содержит такие же сущности в глубину, тогда да - это дерево, если любые другие сущности тогда нет. Смысл дерева в том, что каждый узел реализует одинаковый контракт. Приведите пример Вашей сущности.

Comment: Наверное Вы правы, это не дерево, т.к. это будут разные сущности. Скорее это просто контейнеры. Просто собраны они должны в какую-то иерархию, с несколькими направлениями наследования (не знаю как правильно это назвать, ветьвью я так понял нельзя, т.к. сущности разные и соответственно применить один интерфейс нельзя.)

Comment: Все таки хочется увидеть пример, чтоб понимать. Если не дерево, то нужно очертить для себя их взаимоотношение, наследование, композиция или агрегация.

Comment: Да как бы примера  и нет, я же не могу выбрать структуру. К примеру есть родительский класс, который будет хранить несколько сущностей разной глубины. Вложенные сущности, это фактически HasMap,  но над маппой должна быть обертка в виде класса (setter/getter) для работы с ней (для восприятия человеком, так удобней.)